# The minimal uncountable well-ordered set has no largest element

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

> Theorem. There exists a well ordered set $A$ having a largest element $\Omega$ such that the section $S_\Omega$  of $A$ by $\Omega$ is uncountable but every other section of $A$ is countable.
>
> Proof. Consider an uncountable well ordered set $B$, consider $C=\{1,2\}\times B$ with the lexicographic order and let $\Omega $ be the smallest element of $C$ for which $S_\Omega=\{x\in C| x<\Omega\}$ is uncountable. Let $A=S_\Omega\cup\{\Omega\}$
>   .

I'm trying to show that $S_\Omega$ has no largest element.

Assume the converse: there is $\Gamma\in S_\Omega$ such that $x\le \Gamma$ for all $x\in S_\Omega$. I need to use that $\Gamma $ is a largest element. It's essential to consider $S_\Gamma$ ($\Gamma\in C$, and $S_\Gamma$ is the section of $C$ by $\Gamma$). Then $S_\Gamma$ is countable. At the same time $S_\Omega$ is not. But I don't see any contradiction here... I guess I need to invoke $\Omega$ and prove something like $S_\Omega\cup\{\Omega\}=S_\Gamma$. But I don't see why this holds. $$S_\Gamma=\{x\in C: x\le \Gamma\}
\\ S_\Omega\cup\{\Omega\}=\{x\in C: x\le \Omega\}$$
Do I need to use $x\le \Gamma$ for all $x\in S_\Omega$ somehow to prove the equality? I don't see how.

Comment: Well, for infinite sets $X$ with an element $x\in X$, the complement of $x$, i.e. $X\setminus\{x\}$, is equipotent to $X$. Is that what you want?

Comment: It may help to realize that every infinite ordinal looks like a limit ordinal (no largest element) followed by a finite number (possibly zero) additional elements at the end.  Removing the finite number of additional elements will make the ordinal smaller and will not change the cardinality of the ordinal.

Comment: Certainly $S_\Omega\cup\{\Omega\}\neq S_\Gamma$, since $\Omega\not\in S_\Omega$ and $S_\Gamma$ is a subset of $S_\Omega$.  I would suggest you think about how $S_\Gamma$ and $S_\Omega$ are related.  If it's not obvious, draw a picture of where all the relevant elements are in your well-ordered set.

Comment: @Lubin I'm not sure that's what I want because for now I don't see how I can apply it.

Comment: @Carl Mummert Sorry, I don't know anything about ordinals...

Comment: @user531587: well ordered sets.  You are directly looking at an important ordinal, $\Omega$. We call them ordinals when we think of them "up to isomorphism", i.e. we don't really care about the elements, just the structure of the ordering.

Comment: @EricWofsey I have no idea how to draw pictures in such settings.. The only relation between $S_\Gamma$ and $S_\Omega$ I can think of (except the incorrect one I already mentioned) is $S_\Gamma\cup\{\Gamma\}=S_\Omega$. But after writing out both definitions I can't see why this should hold.

Comment: @Carl Mummert It's Lemma 10.2 from Munkres. The proof says about $\{1,2\}\times B$, not $B\times \{1,2\}$, I didn't quite understand where you got $B\times \{1,2\}$ from.

Comment: @Carl Mummert Sorry, I had a typo. The notes you gave is precisely what Munkres says in the book.

Comment: The proof is better now after the edit.   So you can show that if $S_\Omega$ had a largest element $\alpha$ then $S_\alpha$ would also be uncountable, contradicting the choice of $\Omega$ as the smallest element with an uncountable section.

Comment: @Carl Mummert Now I think the equality from my comment above, which I claimed to be unclear, is obvious. $\Gamma\in S_\Omega$ by the definition of $\Gamma$. Moreover, $S_\Gamma\subset S_\Omega$ since if $t < \Gamma$, then $t < \Omega$. So $S_\Gamma\cup\{\Gamma\}\subseteq S_\Omega$. Let $x\in S_\Omega$. Then $x\le \Gamma$ since $\Gamma$ is a largest element, so $x\in S_\Gamma\cup\{\Gamma\}$. Thus $S_\Gamma\cup \{\Gamma\}=S_\Omega$. Since $S_\Omega$ is uncountable, $S_\Gamma$ must be uncountable, but for any $\Omega\ne a\in C, S_a$ is countable, a contradiction. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that looks right to me.   You can post it as answer here to your own question, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $S_\Gamma\cup\{\Gamma\}=S_\Omega$ holds. Indeed, let $x\in S_\Gamma\cup\{\Gamma\}$. If $x=\Gamma$, then $x\in S_\Omega$ by the definition of $\Gamma$. If $x\in S_\Gamma$, then $x\in S_\Omega$ because $\Gamma \in S_\Omega$ (and so if $x\le \Gamma$, then $x < \Omega$). Thus $S_\Gamma\cup\{\Gamma\}\subseteq S_\Omega$. Conversely, let $x\in S_\Omega$. Since $\Gamma$ is a largest element, $x\le \Gamma$, which means $x\in  S_\Gamma\cup\{\Gamma\}$. Thus $S_\Gamma\cup\{\Gamma\}=S_\Omega$.

Now $S_\Omega$ is uncountable, so $S_\Gamma$ must be uncountable. However, for any $t\in C$ with $t\ne \Omega$ (in particular for $t=\Gamma$; note that $\Gamma\ne \Omega$ because $\Gamma\in S_\Omega$ and $\Omega\notin S_\Omega$), $S_t$ is countable. This is a contradiction.